# Unreal Engine for 2d in c++

Tags: 2d, performance, unreal-4, development-speed

I was about to start my journey on unreal engine but currently all of the tutorials we're all about blueprints in 2D games. I really want to make 2d games since I am not good at 3d (not yet). My concern is ,all their tutorials where blueprints (not really) but most of its 2d tutorials we're  made in blueprint. **Is blueprint that good and powerful than C++ in 2d game developement for UE4 or this is just an advertisement for this features?** I really want more power that is why I really want to use c++ in UE4,

Main purpose is for desktop and console games only. (I don't care about the mobile industry, I prefer cocos if focusing on mobile).

Answer (score 0):

Blueprints are designer-friendly, so that you can introduce code-like behaviour from a friendly interface without actually writing code. Mind you, you can use C++ to achieve the same goal. When you write your C++ code, you can add some macros (UE tutorials show how) in your code to make it "visible" as blueprints. It's not an advertisement; it's a really good and flexible system, I'm currently learning about it myself.

Answer (score 0):

I read your question as can you use C++ to make 2D games in Unreal, to which the short answer is **yes**. Some key points to bear in mind:

**Everything you can do in blueprint, you can do in C++**. So if you feel more comfortable in making your game in C++, it is fairly straight forward to follow blueprint tutorials and implement them in C++. A few bits and pieces like latent actions (e.g. delay nodes) are slightly more fiddly to implement in C++ but certainly not hard.

**Some things can only be done in C++** . Not loads, and not many that you are likely to need, so if you'd prefer to use blueprint you'll mostly be fine. If you've seen BP tutorials that cover everything you want to do, then obviously this is not an issue.

Personally, if you feel comfortable with C++, I would use that. You certainly won't be limited by this choice and, as [@Babis's answer points out](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/103392/10133), you can mark up your C++ which allows you to extend it in blueprint using the editor.

Crucially, whatever you choose, you are not stuck with it. Start with BP and find something you can't do without code: no problem, add some code to your project. Start with code but find recompile times tedious: mark up your code so you can access it from BP and continue. For best results you'll probably want to mix and match.